# Safe way to know if user is logged in client side with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, cookies

My website project shows user specific data in almost every page (e.g. show username in topbar if logged which is existent in all pages), show liked items, etc...

I use AJAX to get html fragments depending if the user is authenticated or not (e.g. show username in topbar if authenticated, otherwise signup/login buttons).

My question is, the above method causes me to invoke AJAX GET request in almost all pages and subsequently at least doubles the HTTP requests & the server load, is it safe to add some cookie `logged_in: true` and check it so I invoke the AJAX GET request ONLY IF the user is logged in.

The convention in Django and modern webdev is to add only the session id in the cookies and everything is in the server side, is there a safe way to know if the user is logged in client side?

Answer (score 1):

In your template, use `is_authenticated` to conditionally make the ajax requests.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

<!-- make the ajax requests -->

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that wouldn't work well in my case because I cache most of the page. I use AJAX to overcome the slow computations in my pages.